# changing build string for conda package

Tags: conda-build

When I first ran `conda-build myrecipe` the tar.bz2 had the name 'mypackage-version-py38_0.tar.bz2' however every time I have run it since, the build string is 'mypackage-version-py38head00f5_0.tar.bz2'. Why is 'head00f5' now being added to the build string?

Here is my meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: mypackage
  version: "0.0.0.dev1"

source:
  path: ../

build:
  number: 0


requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - numpy

  run:
    - python
    - numpy

test:
  imports:
    - mypackage
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 3.0, `conda-build` has been adding hashes to the build string.  See [Differentiating packages built with different variants](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html?highlight=variants#differentiating-packages-built-with-different-variants) for more details.

The hash always starts with `h` and then has 7 hexadecimal numbers.  In your particular case it happens to produce the word `head`, which I'm guessing is part of the confusion.  I think that's just a coincidence.

Comment: Ok, this is makes sense. I think I was missing numpy in my build requirements for the first build and adding it the second time lead to the hash being included. Thanks!